# dcast: converting long to wide with replicates

Tags: r, data.table, reshape, dcast

I am trying to convert a wide dataframe with various dose response intensities with multiple readouts and replicates into a wide format for fitting.

the long data looks like this:

```
ionidx=c(1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 
2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 
2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 
1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 
2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 
2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 
1L)

intensities=c(28396L, 11328L, 10496L, 32674L, 9832L, 28931L, 10580L, 30144L, 
11031L, 29720L, 30292L, 9970L, 10140L, 32286L, 31459L, 8709L, 
8332L, 31830L, 9305L, 29685L, 28933L, 11339L, 12282L, 31594L, 
12763L, 31110L, 10498L, 31405L, 32290L, 11869L, 29295L, 10743L, 
9760L, 29191L, 30020L, 8818L, 32139L, 9605L, 10668L, 31812L, 
9685L, 30365L, 8908L, 30555L, 30919L, 7640L, 8818L, 32864L, 8174L, 
30384L, 29411L, 7902L, 29947L, 8922L, 6936L, 30039L, 7798L, 8520L, 
31842L, 7008L, 28703L, 8745L, 31581L, 7600L, 28301L, 7408L, 31146L, 
12223L, 28793L, 33500L, 13359L, 31791L, 10325L, 11264L, 30491L, 
11396L, 31127L, 10655L, 32256L, 8517L, 31297L, 9000L, 30800L, 
30774L, 8845L, 7903L, 29414L, 8245L, 30337L, 8530L, 30812L, 31559L, 
8280L, 27926L, 8263L, 32300L)

dose=c(5, 5, 1.6667, 1.6667, 1.6667, 1.6667, 0.5556, 0.5556, 0.5556, 
0.5556, 0.1852, 0.1852, 0.1852, 0.1852, 0.0617, 0.0617, 0.0617, 
0.0617, 0.0617, 0.0617, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 1.6667, 1.6667, 1.6667, 
1.6667, 0.5556, 0.5556, 0.5556, 0.5556, 0.5556, 0.5556, 0.1852, 
0.1852, 0.1852, 0.1852, 0.1852, 0.1852, 0.0617, 0.0617, 0.0617, 
0.0617, 0.0617, 0.0617, 0.0206, 0.0206, 0.0206, 0.0206, 0.0206, 
0.0206, 0.0023, 0.0069, 0.0069, 0.0069, 0.0069, 0.0023, 0.0023, 
0.0023, 0.0023, 0.0023, 0.0023, 0.0023, 0.0023, 5, 5, 5, 5, 1.6667, 
1.6667, 1.6667, 1.6667, 0.5556, 0.5556, 0.1852, 0.1852, 0.0206, 
0.0206, 0.0206, 0.0206, 0.0206, 0.0206, 0.0069, 0.0069, 0.0069, 
0.0069, 0.0069, 0.0069, 0.0069, 0.0069, 0.0023, 0.0023, 0.0023
)

resp=data.frame(ionidx=ionidx,intensities=intensities,dose=dose)
```

Desired format would be first `col=ionidx` and subsequent cols are [dose]_[replicate_num]

[image]

Tried using dcast:

```
library(data.table)

dcast(setDT(resp), ionidx~dose+rowid(ionidx), value.var="intensities")
```

but that does not look right. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: u r just missing one more variable in your `rowid`: `dcast(setDT(resp), ionidx ~ dose + rowid(ionidx, dose), value.var="intensities")`

Answer (score 1):

It appears that the replicate number is defined as a sequence along the repeated number of doses for each dose-ionidx combination. This is not what is happening in your `dcast` call, where `rowid(ionidx)` creates two sequences along the levels of `ionidx`. To reproduce the output shown in the image, try:

```r
library(data.table)

setDT(resp)

## add replicate number
resp[, id := seq_len(.N), by = c("dose", "ionidx")]
## cast to wide format
dcast(resp, ionidx ~ dose + id, value.var = "intensities")
#>    ionidx 0.0023_1 0.0023_2 0.0023_3 0.0023_4 0.0023_5 0.0023_6 0.0069_1
#> 1:      1    28703    31581    28301    31146    27926    32300    30039
#> 2:      2     6936     7008     8745     7600     7408     8263     7798
#>    0.0069_2 0.0069_3 0.0069_4 0.0069_5 0.0069_6 0.0206_1 0.0206_2 0.0206_3
#> 1:    31842    29414    30337    30812    31559    30384    29411    29947
#> 2:     8520     7903     8245     8530     8280     8174     7902     8922
#>    0.0206_4 0.0206_5 0.0206_6 0.0617_1 0.0617_2 0.0617_3 0.0617_4 0.0617_5
#> 1:    31297    30800    30774    31459    31830    29685    30555    30919
#> 2:     8517     9000     8845     8709     8332     9305     8908     7640
#>    0.0617_6 0.1852_1 0.1852_2 0.1852_3 0.1852_4 0.1852_5 0.1852_6 0.5556_1
#> 1:    32864    30292    32286    32139    31812    30365    32256    30144
#> 2:     8818     9970    10140     9605    10668     9685    10655    10580
#>    0.5556_2 0.5556_3 0.5556_4 0.5556_5 0.5556_6 1.6667_1 1.6667_2 1.6667_3
#> 1:    29720    29295    29191    30020    31127    32674    28931    31405
#> 2:    11031    10743     9760     8818    11396    10496     9832    10498
#>    1.6667_4 1.6667_5 1.6667_6   5_1   5_2   5_3   5_4   5_5   5_6
#> 1:    32290    31791    30491 28396 28933 31594 31110 28793 33500
#> 2:    11869    10325    11264 11328 11339 12282 12763 12223 13359
```